# server Error : class java.lang.NullPointerException in JSF2.2 web application

Tags: jsf

Hello and thanks in advance for any help you provide.My web application is a dynamic java compiler using the javax.tools package.I provide u with a simplistic overview of my code.

**Compiler class:**

```
  public class Compiler {

    public Compiler(){

    }

    public String compile() throws Exception {
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector diagCollector = new DiagnosticCollector();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagCollector, null, null);
        File outputFile = new File("C:\\Java Projects\\WA9\\src\\java\\compiledFiles");
        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(outputFile));
        String sourceCode = "public class Test{}";
        String sourceFile = "Test.java";
        JavaFileObject sourceObject = new CompilerJavaObject(sourceFile, sourceCode);
        Iterable<JavaFileObject> fileObjects = Arrays.asList(sourceObject);
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagCollector, null, null, fileObjects);
        String message = "Compilation Success";
        if (!task.call()) {
            List<Diagnostic> diagErrors = diagCollector.getDiagnostics();
            for (Diagnostic d : diagErrors) {
                message = ("Error: " + d.getLineNumber() + " Cause: " + d.getMessage(null));
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
```

**SimpleJavaFileObject**

```
public class CompilerJavaObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
     String contents = null;

    public CompilerJavaObject(String sourceName, String contents) throws Exception {
        super(new URI(sourceName), JavaFileObject.Kind.SOURCE);
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean encodingErrors) {
        return contents;
    } 
}
```

**UserBean**

```
@Named("user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    private Compiler compiler;
    private String compilerMessage;

    public UserBean() {
        compiler = new Compiler();
    }

    public void compile() throws Exception {
        compilerMessage = compiler.compile();
    }

    public String getCompilerMessage() {
        return compilerMessage;
    }  
}
```

In my index.xhtml page i have :

```
<h:outputText id="msg" value="#{user.compilerMessage}"/>
<h:commandButton value="Compile">
<f:ajax render="msg" listener="#{user.compile()}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

The problem occurs when i press the compile button in my page i get pop up from localhost with message server error: class.java.lang.NullPointerException and i cant trace the cause of the error.
Is it a mistake in the initialization of my Compiler object in the bean or some of the string variables?
Thanks again for any help u provide.

Comment: The answer is in the stack trace. It's be wise to lookup and share that. By the way, are you implying that this works fine when being executed as standalone Java application with `main()` method and not via a JSF form?

Comment: No off course i just did not want to add the rest of my JSF page.I saw the stack trace the problem occurs with the ToolProvider giving a null JavaCompiler object.The specification says that it may  return a JavaCompiler object or null.I just cant figure why it returns a null object.